# WPF DataGrid top left select all header button doesn't focus the grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

My control uses a WPF DataGrid. If you click the empty header in the top left it selects all rows. This is a standard part of DataGrid, not anything I've added.

However, my users are having trouble because this 'button' doesn't focus the DataGrid. How can I fix this?

[System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.95).aspx)

Edit: This is the Excel analogue of the DataGrid button I am talking about. It's not a true button, but a header of some kind:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) you can notice this button.

[image]

So you can write event handler to `Click` event for this button and in this handler you can focus the grid.

```
private void myGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    Border border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dg, 0) as Border;
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0) as ScrollViewer;
    Grid grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollViewer, 0) as Grid;
    Button button = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, 0) as Button;

    if (button != null && button.Command != null && button.Command == DataGrid.SelectAllCommand)
    {
        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
    }         
}

void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
    myGrid.Focus();           
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used an alternative that doesn't rely on the the visual tree for the control:

In the XAML:

```
<DataGrid.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command="SelectAll" Executed="MyGrid_SelectAll"/></DataGrid.CommandBindings>
```

In the code:

```
private void MyGrid_SelectAll(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        myGrid.Focus();
        if (myGrid.SelectedCells.Count == myGrid.Columns.Count * myGrid.Items.Count)
        {
            myGrid.SelectedCells.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            myGrid.SelectAll();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

This also gave me the ability to implement deselect all if all cells are selected.

Comment: Nicer solution I'd say, but I think maybe you should remove the extra code for deselecting the cells since it isn't what the OP was asking about. Without that, you've got a very clear and simple answer that feels much more declarative than the accepted answer.
One thing I wasn't clear on from your answer was that you do still have to do myGrid.SelectAll() for it to work even if you set e.Handled to false